# Regex Apostrophe how to match?

Tags: python, regex

I want to add to this rule match on **Apostrophe** `'`

```
rule = re.compile(r'^[^*$<,>?!]*$')
```

I have tried:

```
rule = re.compile(r'^[^*$<,>?!']*$')
```

but it sees the apostrophe as a line error, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error comes because you cannot directly use a single `'` inside `''` and similarly single `"` can't be used inside `""` because this confuses python and now it doesn't know where the string actually ends.

You can use either double quotes or escape the single quote with  a `'\'`:

```
rule = re.compile(r"^[^*$<,>?!']*$")
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> strs = 'can\'t'
>>> print strs
can't
>>> strs = "can't"
>>> print strs
can't
>>> 'can't'  #wrong, SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> "can"t"  #wrong, SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to escape the apostrophe, otherwise it will be counted as the end of the raw string:

```
rule = re.compile(r'^[^*$<,>?!\']*$')
```

Or, you can use `"` to surround your string, which is perfectly valid in python:

```
rule = re.compile(r"^[^*$<,>?!']*$")
```