# Python Regex to find image source

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python and I am trying to get **alt** and **images source** from a website, but I am facing problem with the quote `'` and `"`

```
import requests,urllib,urllib2,re

rule = re.compile(r'^[^*$<,>?!\']*$')

r = requests.get('http://www.hotstar.com/channels/star-plus')
match = re.compile('<img alt="(.*?)" ng-mouseleave="mouseLeaveCard()" ng-mouseenter="mouseEnterCard()" ng-click="mouseEnterCard(true)" ng-class="{\'dull-img\': isThumbnailTitleVisible || isRegionalLanguageVisible}" class="show-card imgtag card-minheight-hc ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" placeholder-img="{\'realUrl\' :  \'(.*?)\', \'placeholderUrl\' : \'./img/placeholder/hs.jpg\'}" ng-if="record.urlPictures" src="(.*?)" style="display: block;">',re.DOTALL).findall(r.content)
for name,img,image in match:
```

I can only use the standard Python library.

I've read about defining rule so I did from this: [Regex Apostrophe how to match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486765/regex-apostrophe-how-to-match)

Honestly, I don't know how to use it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your input and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use a parser instead:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('http://www.hotstar.com/channels/star-plus')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
imgs = soup.findAll('img')
for img in imgs:
    print(img["alt"])
```

Comment: This gives me the following output: *

Comment: @Ohumeronen: I know. It prints out all the `alt` attributes of each image found.

Comment: @Jan i am also getting output as `*` nothing else

Comment: @MarkPole: What exactly do you want as output? The image source? Just change it to `img['src']` then.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at this problem and I tried to look in to and I found a few different ways to go about it from looking at the links below. It looks like something like this has happened to other people. I took a quick glance at it, and thought maybe these might help. Try looking at a few of the pages below:

Possibly similar posts:

- [Regex Apostrophe how to match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486765/regex-apostrophe-how-to-match)
- [BeautifulSoup: Extract img alt data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696745/beautifulsoup-extract-img-alt-data)
- [Regex for search and get the src of a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710315/regex-for-search-and-get-the-src-of-a-image)

Then you could also try looking at [Python's Regular Expression Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).